# Convert stringified json objects to json

Tags: python, json, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB, and unfortunately, json objects are returned as strings. I want to convert these stringified json objects back to json, but the problem is - I only want to do so if they are actually json objects, and ignore all fields that are, for example, just normal strings (but **can** convert to json without causing an error).

My approach to do this, is to check if the string contains a double-quote, but this seems a bit too naive, because it will also convert a string which just naturally contains a double quote, but isn't intended as a json object. Is there a more robust way to achieve this?

```
import json
results = {"not_string": 1234,
           "not_json": "1234",
           "json": '[{"json": "1234"}]',
           "false_positive": '["actually a quote in brackets"]'}

# load the json fields in the results
for key, value in results.items():
    if isinstance(value, str) and '"' in value:
        try:
            results[key] = json.loads(value)
        except Exception as e:
            pass
for key, value in results.items():
    print(type(value))
```

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>  <--
```

Expected:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'str'>  <--
```

basically, I dont want to rely on "asking for forgiveness", because the string can be converted to json without causing an error, but this is a false-positive and shouldn't be done.

Comment: Why should that be considered a special case? Both of the last two are valid arrays.

Comment: You'll need to clarify the exact specifications on what is considered allowed.

Comment: How do you distinguish between "real" json you want to convert and "fake"one (i.e. the false-positives), i.e. what is the criteria explained in plane language

Comment: Also, if this comes from DB, isn't supposed that all values from given column would be JSON/not JSON, i.e. convert/not convert? How so you have mixed values column?

Comment: @buran
unfortunately this also happens with the sql function JSON_OBJECT() , which causes the original column types to be lost. The sql builds and returns the object as a string. The syntax is ```select concat('[', group_concat(JSON_OBJECT() separator ','), ']') as json_object ``` . I need to load this object, but not other strings that aren't json objects. I am looking for way to identify these objects, I cannot provide a specification, this is part of the question.

Comment: the question really IS how do I separate stringified json objects from strings. Is there no robust way, other than to look for a double quote? I feel like that there should be something - maybe an even amount of double quotes? or a combination of brackets? At least one colon? Bottom line is, I do not want to load a string which isnt intended to be loaded (buy may succeed to load)...

Comment: `[{"json": "1234"}]` and `["actually a quote in brackets"]` ARE valid JSON. BOTH are. So it's up to you to define a rule why you want to convert one and not the other. i.e. WHY one is OK to convert and the other is treated as false positive. It is NOT about format.

Comment: Also, looking at the `SELECT` statement - it is you who adds `[` and `]`. This is really XY problem, IMHO

Comment: I know that they are both valid jsons, they go through json.loads() without error. I want to sort them out before calling json.loads(), because I do not want to change '["actually a quote in brackets"]' to a list, I want to keep it a string. sorry that this is so confusing. I thought there might be a more in-depth way to check other than checking for a double quote.

Comment: I understand what you want. It seems you don't understand or are unable to articulate a rule how to "sort the out" one way or the other. e.g. checking for double quotes does not work, because both have double quotes

Comment: I don't think you understand that I do not want to convert a value like '1234' to json, I want to keep it a string. json.loads() would convert this to an integer. Checking if the value contains a double quote prevents this. I would like to expand this to other cases, where only checking for a double quote fails...

Comment: `[{"json": "1234"}]` this will be converted to list with one element - a dict, where both key and value will be strings. You still cannot explain how you decide that `'["actually a quote in brackets"]'` should remain string and not converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for this confusing question, I failed to articulate what the goal of this question was.
I want to avoid converting string values to json, even if they would succeed to convert.

for example, i do not want to convert a string of digits ("1234") to json, but I **do** want to convert json objects, such as dictionaries, or an array of dictionaries to json.

What I've come up with is this:

Such json objects contain at least one double-quote (I already defined this in the question)

But, they must also contain an even number of double quotes

And, they should also contain at least one colon -> :

I've expanded my check if the code should convert to json based on these definitions:

```
        if isinstance(value, str) and value.count('"') % 2 == 0 and value.count('"') > 0 and ":" in value:
            try:
                value = json.loads(value)
            except Exception as e:
                # do not change the value
                pass
```

This avoids converting strings which are intended to remain strings, and focuses on converting more complex json objects, such as dictionaries.

I am aware that this may still produce false-positives, but all of this just depends on my use-case. I'm satisfied with this, because I want to focus on dictionaries, and avoid converting stringified integers and arrays which do not contain dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are converting **false_positive** which is a valid list to a string. Here I am providing a solution where **all lists with a single string value will be converted to a string**. Try this code:

```
import json
results = {"not_string": 1234,
           "not_json": "1234",
           "json": '[{"json": "1234"}]',
           "false_positive": '["actually a quote in brackets"]'}

# load the json fields in the results
for key, value in results.items():
    if isinstance(value, str) and '"' in value:
        try:
            temp = json.loads(value)
            if isinstance(temp, list):
                if len(temp) == 1 and isinstance(temp[0], str):
                    results[key] = json.dumps(temp)
                else:
                    results[key] = temp
        except Exception as e:
            pass
for key, value in results.items():
    print(type(value))
    
print(results)
```

This is output:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'str'>
{'not_string': 1234, 'not_json': '1234', 'json': [{'json': '1234'}], 'false_positive': '["actually a quote in brackets"]'}
```

Comment: thank you, but the "false positive" should remain untouched, the result should be 
```{'not_string': 1234, 'not_json': '1234', 'json': [{'json': '1234'}], 'false_positive': '["actually a quote in brackets"]'}```

Comment: I have updated the code as per your comment. Please check it.